# Why is my code did not execute the for-loop in my code?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, pycharm

I created a function and a for-loop, where for-loop has no connection with the function. When code is being executed, the for-loop will be skipped. I want to know why is this happening.

I have a TSV sentiment text file with headers: "positive word count", "negative word count", "total word count" and "text". A function is created to find the average word count, and a for-loop is used to categorize each sentence, and append the "text" into array that its name matches the categorization result. The code runs as intended when I did not call the function, but instead I integrate the calculation in the for-loop. However, I need to know why is this happening as I may not be able to go around every problem like this one.

```py
def get_sentiment_category(p_value, n_value): #has more classification, minimalize
        if p_value is not 0 and n_value is 0:
            return("positive")
        elif p_value is 0 and n_value is not 0:
            return("negative")
```

```
def get_average_word(data):
    total_word = 0
    total_sentence = 0
    for line in data:
        total_sentence += 1
        total_word = total_word + int(line[2])
    return (total_word/total_sentence)
```

```
list_of_category = ["positive","negative"] ## Declare category name
positive = []
negative = []

with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as source:
    source_read = csv.reader(source, delimiter='\t') #reading tsv
    next(source_read, None)#skip header 

    average_word = get_average_word(source_read) ## getting average word
    print("get avg")

    for line in source_read:
        print("1212")
        p_value = int(line[0]) ## positive value
        n_value = int(line[1]) ## negative value
        category = get_sentiment_category(p_value,n_value)
        globals()[category].append(line[3]) ## if category == "positive", line[3](text) will be append to array with name "positive"

print(average_word)
for item in list_of_category:
    print(globals()[item]) 
    print("-----------")
```

```
Sample data:
positive'''negative''' word_count''' text
0''''''''''1'''''''''''3'''''''''''''I am sad
1''''''''''0'''''''''''4'''''''''''''I am very happy

## I do not know to to display TSV, forgive me
```

Output should be:

```
get avg
1212
1212
3.5
["I am sad"]
-----------
["I am very happy"]
-----------
```

Instead:

```
get avg
3.5
[]
-----------
[]
-----------
```

Comment: It's because you're already exhausting the `source_read` generator once you finish `get_average_word`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to handle situation like this?